# How do you change the Export DPI of Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: macos, windows, ms-office, resolution

Office 2016 has on option in the Windows version to alter the export-DPI of PowerPoint by [editing a registry key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/827745/how-to-change-the-export-resolution-of-a-powerpoint-slide),

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

Where would I find this registry key or the equivalent on **the OSX version**?

Comment: Try also. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_mac

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you can change the DPI by altering the width and height upon export.

For example, if you want to export your slides in PNG format, you would:

1. Go to File > Export...
2. In the Export window that appears, select the PNG option from the File Format drop-down list (at bottom centre of window)
3. Now you will see options for Width and Height (see image below):

[image]

4. Now change the value of either option (this will automatically change the other value to ensure you keep the same ratio)

By changing the dimensions, you also change the DPI. For example, a 720x405 image exported from PowerPoint will only be about 54dpi, while doubling this upon export to 1,440x810 will also double the dpi to 108dpi.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue the registry key solved on Windows -- setting a global default that can be used by other applications that use PowerPoint behind-the-scenes to export files.

Answer (score 1):

The functional equivalent of `registry key` on Windows are users defaults on MacOS X.

These users defaults can be managed through the `defaults` command.

To find if there exist the wanted function within the MacOS X version of `PowerPoint` you will have to open a `Terminal` and type exactly:

```
defaults read com.microsoft.PowerPoint
```

which will give the complete list of tunable functions accessible within `PowerPoint`.

From the correct definition of the function you are looking for, you should be able to find which one of these settings has to be changed.
And then you will be able to change it with a command like:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.PowerPoint variable 'value'
```

To get an in depth explanation of this command `defaults` type:

```
man defaults
```

Comment: I had to use the domain `com.microsoft.Powerpoint` (notice the casing difference) to get it to show any settings on my Mac. But alas, I am not seeing any setting that would possibly change the export resolution.